# .NET Core 3 preview 4: 'AddNewtonsoftJson' is not defined

Tags: f#, .net-core-3.0

Using .NET Core 3 preview 4, the "API" template for a F# ASP.NET MVC project fails to build. This is without any changes to the template whatsoever.

[image: "API" template for a F# ASP.NET MVC project]

This is the code that fails:

```fs
type Startup private () =
    member this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson() |> ignore
```

With error

> ...\Startup.fs(23,35): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'AddNewtonsoftJson' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:   AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol

It seems that there are [changes coming for this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7438) - is it just being worked on and unusable right now?

Answer (score 114):

In order to switch ASP.NET Core 3.0 back to use JSON.NET, you will need to reference the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson). That will contain the `AddNewtonsoftJson` extension method.

In C#, this would look like this:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

So assuming that I understand enough of F#, I would say that your call would be correct if you have the package referenced in your project.

Comment: @MortenOC What do you mean by _“does not work”_? Does it not compile, or is JSON not working? `AddControllers` and `AddControllersWithViews` both return the same `MvcBuilder` (just configured differently), so calling `AddNewtonsoftJson()` on that should work just fine.

Comment: turns out I was on a wrong package number.. NewtonsoftJson was not used in controllers with .AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(). Only .AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson() worked

Comment: Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 3.0.0
'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddNewtonsoftJson' and the best extension method overload 'NewtonsoftJsonMvcBuilderExtensions.AddNewtonsoftJson(IMvcBuilder)' requires a receiver of type 'IMvcBuilder'

Comment: @PawelCioch You will need to call `AddControllers()` or something similar first in order to get an MvcBuilder instance. Then you can call `AddNewtonsoftJson()` on that.

Comment: I have `.AddNewtonsoftJson()`, but the controller is still using Text.Json to serialize results.
Is there any other way to change this?

Answer (score 6):

Add package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 
 Package details: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
Call `AddNewtonsoftJson()` extension method as mentioned below

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this helped:

1. Code in Startup.cs

`services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);`

2. Upgrade all Nuget Packages to 3.1.8 (3.1.3 was not working)

Answer (score 2):

It's work for me, Install the NewtonsoftJson package from NuGet
"dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson --version 3.1.0"
version 3.1.0 working for ASP.NET Core 3.0 and use the Following Code-

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => {
            opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Hope it's Working Fine, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use .netcore version 6 the current version of NewtonsoftJson is 7 not supported. later i installed NewtonsoftJson 6 now its working