# I can not use the 'services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, startup

I'm in Net core 3.1 and I'm trying to use `AddNewtonsoftJson()`

I'm getting:

> "IMvcBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddNewtonsoftJson'
> and no accessible extension method 'AddNewtonsoftJson' accepting a
> first argument of type 'IMvcBuilder' could be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)"

This is what I write in my ConfigureService:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

I already have installed NewtonSoft in my startup project.

Comment: Okay, it's a seemingly minor difference, but I'd reopen this one b/c it's in `c#` and the dupe listed is `F#`. I don't want to have to google up enough F# to know it works for both. I want a c# specific answer. (again, I'm pretty sure the F# answer works (as it's even written _for c#_, but it's a completely different tag. What you're really looking for is to move that answer here.)

Comment: Note: This question was previously closed as duplicated on this [related f# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787018/net-core-3-preview-4-addnewtonsoftjson-is-not-defined) that has a useful answer written in c#

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need also to install [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) which contains corresponding extension [methods](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/DependencyInjection/NewtonsoftJsonMvcBuilderExtensions.cs), as written in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-mvc-project) .

Comment: Working perfectly in asp.net Core 6 in 2022.

Answer (score 3):

The package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` is no longer included in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework (aka. meta package in version 2.x) because the new `System.Text.Json` is now mature enough to replace `Newtonsoft.Json` as the built-in json (de)serializer.
Therefore consider replacing all uses of `Newtonsoft.Json` with `System.Text.Json` for performance and futural compatibility.

Only if it is not possible, you could install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package manually, while a direct reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` is no longer need, for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` already references `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: This may be true however System.Text.Json cannot handle Guids with {} simbols. NewtonSoft can. I dont know if {}'s are legally supported for Guids but for my clients some are sending them and some are not so I have to support both cases or rather I choose to support both cases.