# Why are the JSON values emtpy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, json.net

I got a very simple controller that reads json from a local file, parses it into a JObject with JObjects.parse, and then returns it with Ok().

The result shows the JSON, however the values are "empty"

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqQKs.png)

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fv2c.png)

The test JSON i'm using

```
{
    "version": "1.3",
    "status": "ok"
}
```

If I add a breakpoint, the response variable seems to be correctly filled:
[Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJHOt.png)

Does anyone have any clue what could be the issue here?

Comment: Post the code as text in the question itself. Images can't be copied, googled, compiled or tested

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s)? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core for several versions (since 3rd version if I remember correctly) now uses `System.Text.Json` as default serializer, which knows nothing about `JObject` from Newtonsoft one. You need to either switch to Newtonsoft Json (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63087744/2501279) for example) - add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` nuget and use `AddNewtonsoftJson` (for example `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`)

Or use `System.Text.Json` capabilities for example [`JsonNode` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-7-0#use-jsonnode) (available since .NET 6).

Comment: The equivalent of JObject is `JsonElement` or `JsonDocument` (which just wraps a JsonElement). JsonElement (or JsonDocument) is also the type you get if you deserialize as `object`.