# .NET 6 ajax model binding value cannot pass JSON to action

Tags: c#, ajax, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.1, model-binding

I use POSTMAN and set request header with 'Content-Type:application/json' and Body with 'raw:JSON' to send API
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRQAt.png)

```
[HttpPost("CallApi")]
        public string CallApi([FromBody] string val)
        {
            string returnValue = "api:";
            return returnValue + val;
        }
```

I sent "123", I got response with "api:123".
However, if I sent {"val":"123"}, I got an error "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi5Oh.png)

Why I sent JSON string but response with error? What if my API requires two parameters today, how do I send them in JSON format?

"I used to hope that, just like in .NET Core 3, I could directly pass JSON in the body like `{"val1": "a", "val2": "b", "val3": "c"}` to the `[HttpPost]public void Post(string val1, string val2, string val3)` Action and get the response in JSON format."

Answer (score 0):

> Why I sent JSON string but response with error

You are not sending JSON string, you are sending JSON object. ASP.NET Core for several versions uses `System.Text.Json` as default serializer which is quite picky about types JSON token types. You can try using `System.Text.Json` capabilities for dynamic JSON processing (for example [`JsonNode` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-7-0#use-jsonnode), available since .NET 6 or `JsonElement`/`JsonDocument` as type for `val`).

Or you can try using Newtonsoft's Json.NET  - add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` nuget and use `AddNewtonsoftJson` (for example `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63087744/2501279))

Or use