# Newtonsoft DateFormatHandling returns Date string in wrong format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, .net-8.0

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API written in .NET 8. I use Newtonsoft.JSON for serializing JSON output. Below is the configuration for the serializer.

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opts => {
    opts.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
    opts.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
});
```

I expected the `DateTime` in the response to be `MicrosoftDataFormat` but unfortunately they are being converted to ISO dates.  As a test, I made a simple API which returns a `DateTime`. Output looks like following:

```
"2024-01-24T10:36:45.1037373+01:00"
```

My controller action looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("test")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    return Ok(date);
}
```

Has anybody had a similar issue?

Comment: So, you would expect something like  `"\/Date(1356044400000+0100)\/"` (example from NewtonSoft Docs), right?

Comment: The format isn't wrong. That's the standard way or representing dates in JSON.

Comment: The *real* question is why do you want `\/Date(1356044400000+0100)\/` at all? JSON.NET switched to ISO in JSON.NET 4.5, back in 2012. We're now at 13.x and *all* APIS and JS code expect the ISO8601 format. By now, ISO8601 is the standard specified in [RFC 7493](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3) for JSON messages

Comment: Do you have a [mre] you can post somewhere like github?

Comment: Hi Waldo, could you kindly check my answer below, I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems AddNewtonsoftJson does nothing until you install package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.

See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13564

Comment: This method is part of the provided package AFAIK - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63087768/2501279

Answer (score 0):

We should create a custom formatter to implement this requirement.

DateTimeConverter.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
    {
        private const string DateFormat = "/Date({0}+{1})/";

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var offset = new DateTimeOffset(value);
            var milliseconds = new DateTimeOffset(value).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            writer.WriteValue(string.Format(DateFormat, milliseconds, GenerateTimezoneOffset(offset.Offset.Hours)));
        }
        public override DateTime ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DateTime existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var dateString = reader.ReadAsString();
            return DateTime.Parse(dateString);
        }
        public string GenerateTimezoneOffset(int hours)
        {
            int offset = hours * 100;
            return $"{offset:D4}";
        }

    }

}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opts => {
           
    opts.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
});
```

**Test Result**

[image]